# How may I know what patches are exclusive of a git repository that commits in the same branch as the upstream git repository?

Tags: git

I know a git repository where their authors are committing changes in the same branch as the upstream repository and they merge with upstream sometimes.

How may I know what patches are exclusive of a git repository that commits in the same branch as the upstream git repository?

Answer (score 0):

You could try `git cherry`

```
       git-cherry - Find commits not merged upstream

SYNOPSIS
       git cherry [-v] [<upstream> [<head> [<limit>]]]

DESCRIPTION
       The changeset (or "diff") of each commit between the fork-point and
       <head> is compared against each commit between the fork-point and
       <upstream>. The commits are compared with their patch id, obtained from
       the git patch-id program.

       Every commit that doesn't exist in the <upstream> branch has its id
       (sha1) reported, prefixed by a symbol. The ones that have equivalent
       change already in the <upstream> branch are prefixed with a minus (-)
       sign, and those that only exist in the <head> branch are prefixed with
       a plus (+) symbol:
```